# How to create block image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, vision

I have 2000 images, the size of each is Xi=320*512 double (i=1:1:2000). I want to regard each image as one block, so there are 2000 blocks, and then put them in one big image. For each block there is a label corresponding to it, the label ranges from 1 to 10. My question is how to put the 2000 images into a big block images with a label for each block as I described above?

I have 2000 images like this. Can anyone tell me how to put this kind of images into blocks?

Comment: Try using [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).

Comment: @JeffIrwin, Please give me an example

Comment: I'm a little unclear about matching the labels from 1 to 10 with 2000 blocks, what are you wanting to do here?

Comment: @paisanco, I want to do image classification by using sparse coding

Comment: I do not see any labels (did you mean filename?) the image you provided is example of set of input images or just single input image or your desired output? My guess  is it is a set for single label and you want the 3D Voxel matrix from it (like MRI images) so 1. need to find the join position if not aligned already and load the matrix slices one by one... or use some 3D Voxel file format. Please specify a bit closer ...

Answer (score 0):

My comment was incorrect, `reshape` will not solve your problem.  However, I did use `reshape` to create an example array of images.

```
% Replace these with 320, 512, and 2000.
nx = 2;
ny = 3;
nz = 4;

% nz images, each of size nx by ny
images = reshape(1: nx * ny * nz, nx, ny, nz)

% Put each image into a larger image composed of n1 * n2 blocks
n1 = 2;
n2 = 2;
image = zeros(n1 * nx, n2 * ny);

% Note, nz == n1 * n2 must be true

iz = 0;
for i1 = 1: n1
    for i2 = 1: n2
        iz = iz + 1;
        image((i1 - 1) * nx + 1: i1 * nx, (i2 - 1) * ny + 1: i2 * ny) ...
            = images(:, :, iz);
    end
end

image
```

This creates the big block image correctly.  You may want to change the inner/outer order of the loops to do column-major ordering instead of row-major ordering.

Like paisanco, I am unsure what you want to do with labels.